# Repaint(); not calling paint method

Tags: java, paint, repaint

I know that this question has already been asked several times before, but none of them seem to have an answer that works for me.
I am trying to create a game of backgammon, and while I am beginning to work on this I have run into this early problem: The repaint(); is not calling the paintComponent method. I have compared it with some other code of mine that works properly, and I have not found any significant differences.

```
    public class World extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        Player1 p1;
        Player2 p2;
        Board b;
        Timer tm;

        public World()
        {
            setFocusable(true);
            p1 = new Player1();
            p2 = new Player2();
            b = new Board();
            tm = new Timer(5, this);
            tm.start();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            System.out.println("Called World Paint");
            super.paintComponent(g);
            p1.paintComponent(g);
            p2.paintComponent(g);
            b.paintComponent(g);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Called actionPerformed");
            p1.move();
            p2.move();
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

With all of the appropriate imports.
I know for a fact that the actionPerformed method is being accessed.

Comment: Where is the implementation of repaint()?

Comment: Could be that your panel is never added / layout in a displayed window... or so many other reasons... please provide something closer to an executable example...

Comment: Get rid of your `paint` method and override `paintComponent` directly. One reasons a component won't be painted is if it's not actually on the screen, visible, sized and within a paintable region

Comment: I've tried doing that, but it didn't help at all.